# UIPopoverView follow uitextfield cursor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, uikit

So I am trying to implement autocomplete suggestion in a UIPopoverView over a UItextField. My only problem is how to get to popover to point to the suggested word or at least to the end of the text in the textfield.

I believe the key here is the sourcerect property but when set to the uitextfield it always points the center of the textfield.

Comment: The popover you want to show is something similar to native(ios) selection options?

Comment: its a uitableview inside a popoverview

Answer (score 0):

You can find the position of the last text in the UITextfield with 
`let endPosition: UITextPosition = textField.endOfDocument` 
Try to set the popover source to it.